# Get Coordinates Longitude Latitude using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to get current location coordinates longitude and latitude.this code is correctly working on Firefox Microsoft edge.but isn't working properly on google chrome can any modification make it compatible with other browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/juraqo/edit?html,js,output. This works great for me in Google Chrome.

Comment: but it's not providing accurate result.

Comment: How accurate are you looking for?

Comment: Atleas in the radius of one km.

Comment: Mine was within 10 meters (using Chrome). I'm in a major city though. In rural areas it can be worse. How far off was yours?

Comment: Chrome provides me these coordinates which is about 12 KM away from me!

Latitude: 31.418714199999997
Longitude: 73.07910729999999

AND my current coordinates are these Firefox providing it with same code. 

Latitude: 31.47169
Longitude: 73.12875

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is related to the fact, that Chrome blocks the localization for applications run from file system (i.e. from disk).
Have you deployed it on any kind of web server?

Comment: oh! yes it's working by deploying on local server but still it not producing such accurate result!!

Comment: The location quality will depend on your device. It should try using information from GPS (if it has one), WiFi (if enabled and your area has been mapped for WiFi signals) and IP (low quality). If you believe that a better localization quality may be obtained in your area and on your device maybe you could try using a handler for [`watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Watching_the_current_position)